# How to adjust the position of an image in an HGroup aligned vertically by baseline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a `HGroup` with a few `Labels` and an `Image`. The `HGroup` has `verticalAlign` set to `baseline`. All the `Labels` line up correctly. The `Image` does not. The `Image` is much too low.

Is there a property or style to adjust the vertical position of the `Image`? It looks like the `HGroup` uses `baseline` or `baselinePosition` to position the `Labels`. It looks like `Image` has that property and style as well but it doesn't seem to do anything when I change it.

Example code:

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="baseline"
          top="10"
          right="10"
          left="10">
    <s:Button label="Previous"/>

    <s:Label text="Total results:" />

    <s:Image height="28" width="100"
             source="myImage.png"
             />

    <s:Spacer width="100%"/>

    <s:Button label="Next" />
</s:HGroup>
```

`HorizontalLayout` has a method called `calculateBaselineTopBottom()` and it's called in `updateDisplayListReal()`. It seems it is doing something with `baseline` and `baselinePosition`. It also seems to use `alignmentBaseline`. So far in my tests it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like setting the `baseline` property does it. It wasn't working because in my tests I was passing a `String` value (well, it was converted to a `String` along the way). So it needs to be passed as a `Number`. The `baseline` property accepts `Objects` which is why it would accept `String` or `Number`.

It also accepts negative values. So the following works:

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="baseline"
          top="10"
          right="10"
          left="10">
    <s:Button label="Previous"/>

    <s:Label text="Total results:" />

    <s:Image height="28" width="100"
             source="myImage.png"
             baseline="-8"
             />

    <s:Spacer width="100%"/>

    <s:Button label="Next" />
</s:HGroup>
```